# Django Nonrel Login `name should be a string`

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

As the title says, I'm trying to just use basic Django authentication on django-nonrel. Nothing fancy:

Here's a basic login view:

```
def login_user(request):
    """Basic login page."""
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'blog/login.html')
```

As soon as I try to `login(request, user)`, or even a `logout(request)`, I only ever get the following error:

```
name should be a string; received <bound method Key.name of datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'django_session', u'www4x1yrgzcnk6xr6giw5dll89wn6rz7', _app=u'dev~cjapolloblog')> (a instancemethod):
```

And I have no idea why. I can't find any documentation or mention of this error anywhere - apparently this should be working fine.

(Using the GAE Datastore)

Comment: Have you tried warping the username and password in a str() ?

Comment: Still get the error. The `authenticate(...)` seems to work, it's the `login` and `logout` that cause the error.

Comment: This error is not from this code.  It is from your `Sessions` handling.  Do you have`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` in your middleware in `settings.py`?  Check your datastore viewer for this session (`www4x1yrgzcnk6xr6giw5dll89wn6rz7`), and see what it has for `name`